# I'm getting "Unsupported OAuth version or server" when trying to sign in via Google

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, google-openid

I'm getting the error "Unsupported OAuth version or server" when trying to sign in via Google. What's the deal?

I went to https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ and wrote a question. Before I submittted it, I clicked on the sign in via google button. It brought me to a page that said "Unsupported OAuth version or server". I tried it again several times with the same effect.

Using Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m on windows 8 64 bit

Comment: If someone gave you a bug report that effectively said "what's the deal with `x`", what would you tell them? Try to include some more details to help the developers isolate the problem, like steps to reproduce, screen shots, browser  version, etc

Comment: I would expect them to tell me if its a known problem or not. But you have a reasonable point, i'll add some details

Comment: If it's a known problem, you would be able to [search for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search). What web browser and which version are you using?

Comment: Weird. The only other report ever made [was deleted by a dev few years after being posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65513/stack-exchange-login-not-working-with-delegation). Looks like nothing on Stack Exchange side.

Comment: @Doorknob Updated the question to have the version ^

Comment: Reproduced. Looking into it.

Comment: Better hope this is fixed soon, as it's sure to be a great question! ;) (from an [earthscience.se] mod)

Comment: Fun fact: the details here (specifically, that you clicked "sign up" from the Ask Question page) were quite relevant. :)

Comment: @hichris123 Already posted it as a guest! http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/does-the-long-term-ice-core-temperature-record-provide-reasonable-evidence-that

Comment: @AnnaLear You know whats stupid? I'm a developer myself, and I would have hated my initial question as a bug report. I'm usually good about that, but I think the fact that this is a stack-overflow-like situation changed the way i decided to write about it.

Comment: @BT Oh, that's your question. Btw, you should have someone merge your accounts when this is fixed (just poke Anna with a non-sharp/pointy stick. ;))

Comment: @BT your edit is exactly what I was trying to suggest.  The bug report is much more complete now.  Thanks for taking my feedback.

Comment: That's a good idea hichris, @AnnaLear mind obliging when you have a sec?

Comment: @BT Sure thing. Merged. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next prod build - likely sometime on Monday. In the meantime, kindly hit "sign up" from the top bar first and then ask your question. :)

The gist of the issue here is that we switched to Google OAuth2 a bit ago since they're phasing out their OpenID support, but we forgot to update one of the views.

Comment: Ah, i'm surprised you guys have that kind of code duplication, tho maybe I shouldn't be

Comment: @BT Yeah, I'm with you there. It's on my list to clean this sort of thing up. Next week's theme is "Paying Down Technical Debt". :)