# What are the plans regarding OpenID / OpenID Connect?

Tags: support, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

The OpenID protocol that is used by Stack Exchange websites [has been obsolete for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689865/284111).

Is it going to be upgraded to something that is not obsolete? [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) comes to mind.

Answer (score -3):

With the current global login system, the only thing SE really *needs* OpenID (or anything similar) for is people who log in using external credentials from Google / Facebook / etc. (and also a few historical special cases like [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com), but those really should be fixed anyway).

So I suspect the answer is "whatever Google, Facebook and other major identity hubs will support."  And [Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238813) and [Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141689) are already using OAuth anyway.

Comment: I think they meant are we going to update our [in-house OpenID service](http://openid.stackexchange.com) which is what our standard email/password logins actually use - we've used OAuth for Google, Facebook, and the like for many years.